# How to do other "stuff" in the same terminal where you establish an SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I often use an ssh tunnel. I open up one terminal to create the tunnel (e.g. `ssh -L 1111:servera:2222 user@serverb`). Then I open a new terminal to do my work. Is there a way to establish the tunnel in a terminal and somehow put it in the background so I don't need to open up a new terminal? I tried putting "&" at the end, but that didn't do the trick. The tunnel went into the background before I could enter the password. Then I did `fg`, entered the password and I was stuck in the ssh session.

I know one possible solution would be to use screen or tmux or something like that. Is there a simple solution I'm missing?

Comment: have a look at [x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php)!

Answer (score 3):

There is the `-f` and `-N` options exactly for that:

```
-f     Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.  This is useful if
       ssh is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the
       background. This implies -n. The recommended way to start X11 programs at a remote
       site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.

       If  the  ExitOnForwardFailure  configuration option is set to ``yes'', then a client 
       started with -f will wait for all remote port forwards to be successfully established
       before placing itself in the background.

-N     Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports
       (protocol version 2 only).
```

So the full command would be `ssh -fNL 1111:servera:2222 user@serverb`.

A way to prevent ssh asking for the password would also be to use [SSH public keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys) for authentication with an agent that either saves the password or prompts it using an external graphical program such as pinentry.

It might also be useful for you to look into [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/), which will reconnect your SSH automatically if the connection drops.

Comment: I tried `ssh -f -L 1234:servera:5678 user@serverb` and got `Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.`

Comment: Yes, I've been lazy about setting up keys. Haven't made the effort to learn how to do it. autossh looks interesting.

Comment: Add the `-N` parameter to fix that.